# Getting The print servers in a network

Tags: powershell, networking, printing

I want to write a PowerShell script to get all the print servers in a network.

I have used the following LDAP query, but it returns only servers with network printers attached to it. But not other print servers that have a remote printer attached to it.
Here's the code I used to get the print servers (But getting only the servers with n/w printers)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[array]$testarray = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(&(&(uncName=*)(objectCategory=printQueue))))" -properties *|Sort-Object -Unique -Property servername |select servername
$testarray
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `Get-WMIObject win32_printer | select name,local` wrapped in a `foreach-object` loop like this:

```
$servers | ForEach-Object {
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -computername $_ | Where-Object {$_.local -like 'False'} | select Name,local,SystemName | format-table -a
}
```

The `$servers` can be what scoped to whatever servers you need to check.

Use `Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer | select *` to see what properties you want to report back on and include them in the `| select Name,local,SystemName` section of the script

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `Get-ADComputer` and `Get-Printer` to list all shared printer queues on computers joined to your domain:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | % {
  $computer = $_.Name
  Get-Printer -Computer $computer | ? { $_.Shared } | select -Expand Name
}
```

This doesn't cover computers that aren't domain members, though.